# In what situations it should be use a symbol "-" in the title of pages?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, title

Examples for understanding, please tell me by your experience, is it good to use?

```
Name_of_film - watch online
Name_of_season_2_episode_4 - watch anime
Name_of_book - read
```

Like the main aim, what to do and - between them. Some people told me, that any language's symbols is not good for title, but I think, it's more beautifull and also for seo

Answer (score 2):

It should not affect SEO at all if not overused. It's a safe rule to not use any special characters in titles, but dash is very universal and yes, as you indicated, it makes it easier to read, which is important since in vast majority of cases, UX is more important than SEO.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what BNazaruk already said, the two non-alphanumeric symbols you will commonly see in title tags are the dash ( - ) and the pipe ( | ). For SEO and branding purposes, people often include one or both in title tags, in order to separate the content and to add the site or business name to every page's title tag.

I like to use the pipe to separate the brand name from the page description, and dashes to make the page description more readable. For example:

*Widget Store | Buy Blue Widgets - for Desktop Computers*

But this is just a personal cosmetic preference (that my clients seem to like).

You should probably stay away from other symbols in your title tags though, to be safe and not have those misinterpreted by either robots or humans.